# Toast throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with appcompat v26 when using fontFamily attribute in theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, toast, font-family

Whenever I show a `Toast`, the app crashes.

The app works fine if I use older version of AppCompat library or remove `fontFamily` from the style.

**onCreate:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //line 13
}
```

**Dependency:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

**AppTheme:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

**Stack Trace:**

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; index=233
>                                                                        at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
>                                                                        at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
>                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1212)
>                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:202)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getString(TintTypedArray.java:143)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:215)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
>                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>                                                                        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:266)
>                                                                        at io.yarsa.blankapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

**Is there any alternative so that I can use the `fontFamily` attribute in theme using the latest version of `AppCompat` library?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add font in Theme like below-

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! One question: Why is it `android:Widget.Holo.Button` instead of `android:Widget.Button`? Would it still be the same if my base theme is using `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`?

Comment: @Aba No, `Holo` style will not create same design. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Android Developer Guide for [fonts in xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

> **Adding fonts to style**
>
> Open the `styles.xml`, and set the `fontFamily` attribute to the font file
>   you want to access.
>
> ```
> <style name="customfontstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
>     <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lobster</item> 
> </style>
> ```

In your case you should put the `@font/` prefix

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sans-serif-light</item>
```